# How strong is windows firewall on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: firewalls, windows-server

How strong is Windows Firewall?

I have no knowledge on Botnets or how to use them, so I have no way to test Windows firewall's strength. And I believe it would go against the contract I signed with my host.

In addition to my host anti DDoS mitigation, and BeeThinks Guardian, my application automatically create a firewall rule that blocks an IP with an incomplete information that my application requested to the client (encrypted keys which change on every request). Multiple handshake request within a certain timeframe, multiple fragmented packets within timeframe or a client holding more ports than "usual".

Can I rely on Windows firewall to "work" until my host's anti-DDoS mitigation micks in (10 Seconds - 1 Minute) or will it just break and crash Windows Server 2019 at some point?

I have also configured my application to create a firewall rule to "allow" a connection through Windows firewall on a certain port if the client is actually using my software. (This rule also gets deleted when it's blocked as stated above.)

Comment: welcome - so to clarify, you want to know if windows server can handle denial-of-service attacks for a period of time until your host's network protections kick in? by the way, have you considered raising the possibility with them of testing their automated protections?

Comment: @brynk , Thank you for the Reply! , I have been attacked by a DDoS for a while since the Application I'm Managing is an Old MMORPG and For a fact I do know that their Anti DDoS mitigation does work, but not until it affects my Application Hence I employed Window's Firewall to "Whitelist" ,for a lack of a better word legitimate clients and Block Unwanted handshakes.

So the answer is Yes, Would Windows Server's Firewall be able to handle the attack until the Mitigation kicks in. 

If it's any help the last attack I got was around 1Gbps.

Comment: @brynk and No, I haven't contacted them yet about "Me" simulating an attack on the server , but on the fine print of the contract I've seen that it's not allowed since it would affect other Services within the same node.

Comment: *Strong*? It drops packets. If the DDoS saturates your pipe a host side firewall won't help you mitigate the consequences. There's no *strength* in firewalls; either they drop (or reject) traffic or they don't. If they don't, they're hardly firewalls.

Comment: @vidarlo That's exactly what I'm asking, I guess you're right Strong is really not the right word. I guess the Question should be , is Windows firewall "Sufficient" to hold back the Attack until the DDoS Mitigation Kicks in.

Comment: If your network pipe is filled with traffic, it's filled. No firewall on your end can mitigate that. If sufficient traffic is sent your way, you *will* effectively be offline, no matter what you do on your end. The traffic *has* to be handled upstream, where the pipe's bigger.

Comment: @vidarlo in no way I'm saying my Bandwidth is saturated. I'm saying it's affecting my Application [ Until the Mitigation Kicks in ] which is why I employed Window's Firewall and hence the question. So my application won't be bothered by the Handshake Request of the attack.

Comment: This depends on the kind of attack. If it is bandwidth - Firewall will not help as already outlined. If it is application based DoS (i.e. lower bandwidth which targets resource usage in your application, like keeping many sockets open or doing complex operations) - firewall will not help either since it has no idea about your application.

Comment: out of interest, what is your application? @vidarlo is correct in that a serious problem must be countered up-stream, but if it is one or two pests, you might simply be able to introduce something like a rate-limiting proxy, eg. a tool called [`haproxy`](https://www.haproxy.org/) which can [impose limits on layer-4 tcp connections](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/application-layer-ddos-attack-protection-with-haproxy/) - scroll down to "Protecting TCP (non-HTTP) Services"

Comment: @brynk Yes I am already using a tool similar to haproxy which is Beethink's Guardian, which works on the level of the network adapter. As of this moment it's simply affecting my Application which is a Game Server, since the attack is coming from a Bot Net which consists of hundreds of IP.

Right now the Beethinks's Guardian Drops and blocks all Connection from an IP may it be spoofed or not when it reaches a certain Handshake or Established Connection. [  I mimicked this behavior on my application's Logic on when to create the firewall to block an IP rules. ]

Comment: @Steffen Ulrich, Thank you!, I understand your point, Yes The firewall doesn't know about my application but my application knows about the traffic so Setting up the firewall rules is handled by my Application.

I guess I should rephrase my question
"If an multiple IP is blocked[ 100 For Example ], could Window's Firewall take it? or would it simply fail or at worst crash windows".

Comment: @AzrielElijay: Blocking an IP address is a comparably easy task - way easier than serving application traffic. So assuming that your system is powerful enough to handle the application traffic on this uplink, then the firewall should be able to handle this too. But, this is only an assumption since nothing is known about the performance of your system and the bandwidth of the uplink.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Thank you for the Reply! So by your comment I'm Assuming the Limiting factor in this situation would be the System itself? i.e. the Firewall won't "Crash" for a lack of a better term as long as the system is powerful enough.

Comment: While firewalls might have bugs in general, this Windows firewall is comparable simple. Thus it might result that the system gets unresponsive due to lots of traffic but not that the firewall itself ceases to work and instead allows full access to the system.